# Launching Ubuntu virtual guest on Virtualbox using command line

Tags: ubuntu, automation, command-line-interface, virtualbox

Is it possible to fully install Ubuntu virtual machine on Virtualbox in a manner that I could export all the machine's file system (to a .vmdk) using only command line?

I've prepared the machine and started it using `VBoxManage` as explained in the following link https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/it-infrastructure/admin-manage-vbox-cli.html, but I couldn't find a way to go through the installation process of picking a language and so on without RDPing to the machine. Is there a way to automate this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can read [Getting started with Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/intro/getting-started/) (`vagrant` is just a wrapper on top of the VirtualBox CLI / API - and can abstract even other hypervisors)

To start an `ubuntu` server you'd just have to create a `Vagrantfile` (no extension if you're on `Windows` (more [vagrant:boxes/ubuntu/bionic64](https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/bionic64) )

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
end
```

and in this folder where the `Vagrantfile` resides, just run:

```
vagrant up
```

You can package your apps using `vagrant` or `packer` and get an `image` file called `.box`.

You can use `Virtualbox` (default) or `vmware` provider or [others](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/providers/)

You can also export the images as simple `.ova` or `ovf` images (also known as templates - [more](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.5/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-AE61948B-C2EE-436E-BAFB-3C7209088552.html) )

Comment: Thanks azbarcea! However, I would like to use my own ISO. Is it possible? It seems that I can use only existing base boxes or create one using GUI.

Comment: Hi @abby, [here](https://github.com/azbarcea/puppet-learning-vm) is an example where from an already existing machine you can build a `.box` of your own and publish it.  The whole idea is to use your own ISO. So, yes, is possible. You basically use your [own ISO setup as disk](https://askubuntu.com/a/64917/513268) to boot and install what you want. That VM you export it as an image (any of `.ovf`, `.ova`, `.box` etc).